# Filtering Python Pandas dataframe so that it matches on the "Daily Oil" column and outputs data from the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, max

I have generated the dataframe below in python which has had a groupby operation used on it to find the max Daily Oil's for each company:

```py
DailyOilMax = dftblOilWells.groupby(['Operator Company Name',"Reservoir"])['Daily Oil'].max().reset_index().sort_values(by='Daily Oil', ascending=False).reset_index()
```

Output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7kPu.jpg

Now I want to go back to the original dataframe below and filter it based on the results above:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5IwP.jpg

I've tried `merge`, `iloc`, but feel like I may need a function for this to work.

```py
dfTest = dfOilWells.loc[dfOilWells.['Daily Oil'].isin(DailyOilMax['Daily Oil'])]
```

I felt close with the code above but couldn't figure out the syntax if my column has a space in it.